# Black Color Behind UIView while UIView Transition Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am doing transition animation using the following block. But I observed that during flip animation a black color layer appears beneath the UIView. Is there any way to set custom color to that layer.

```
UIView.transitionWithView(ibContainerView, duration: 0.2, options: [.CurveEaseOut,.TransitionFlipFromLeft], animations: {
                self.ibContainerView.addSubview(self.ibInstagramView)

                }, completion:nil)

        }
```

Comment: check the background color of View & try to change background color of UIVIew

Comment: that doesn't help as it is not the color of UIView

Comment: I have same problem but can't solve as well

Answer (score 0):

try changing border width and color

```
self.yourView.layer.borderWidth = 0
self.yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

Comment: ohh ok...can you show which layer is coming ?? it so it will help to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the background color of the actual ViewController, which holds all these views.